# Create the same route for each route table per availability zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

At the current moment, I'm creating 3 route tables based on how many availability zones are in my VPC.

This is my code currently:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "nat_gateway_rt" {
  for_each = aws_subnet.subnet_nat_gateway
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.this.id

  route {
    cidr_block      = "0.0.0.0/0"
    vpc_endpoint_id = (aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall.firewall_status.0.sync_states.*.attachment.0.endpoint_id)[1]
  }
  tags = merge(var.tags, {
    "Name" : "rt-nat-gateway-${each.key}"
    }
  )
}
```

What I need to do for the routes is that there is one route per route table per az with a CIDR_BLOCK being 0.0.0.0 and the target being vpc_endpoint.

The VPC Endpoints need to match to the route AZ. At the moment, these VPC Endpoints are filtered via locals

```
 firewall-eu-west-2a = {
    for_each        = aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall
    vpce_eu-west-2a = [for ss in aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall.firewall_status[0].sync_states : ss.attachment[0].endpoint_id if ss.availability_zone == "eu-west-2a"]
  }
  firewall-eu-west-2b = {
    for_each        = aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall
    vpce_eu-west-2b = [for ss in aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall.firewall_status[0].sync_states : ss.attachment[0].endpoint_id if ss.availability_zone == "eu-west-2b"]
  }
  firewall-eu-west-2c = {
    for_each        = aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall
    vpce_eu-west-2c = [for ss in aws_networkfirewall_firewall.sagemaker_network_firewall.firewall_status[0].sync_states : ss.attachment[0].endpoint_id if ss.availability_zone == "eu-west-2c"]
  }
}
```

Essentially, it should be

- The route table in eu-west-1a should have one route of CIDR of
  0.0.0.0 to eu-west-1a endpoint
- The route table in eu-west-1b should have one route of CIDR of 0.0.0.0 to eu-west-1b endpoint
- The route table in eu-west-1c should have one route of CIDR of 0.0.0.0 to
  eu-west-1c endpoint

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: @MarkoE At the minute no, essentially we need to an IF statement on each availability zone to go against the vpc endpoints. 

Creating a dynamic block with the cidr block being 0.0.0.0/0 and vpc_endpoint being the IF statement to do a loop against VPC_Endpoints going against the AZs